# How to arrange a 2x2 data.frame from a single vector

Tags: r, regex

I have the following data.frame:

```
v1<-c("8/12/2018", "hello, how are you", "9/9/2016", "What is going on?","the number three", "9/18/2015", "hello", "9/8/1999","not going", "where to next?")
(df<-as.data.frame(v1, stringsAsFactors=FALSE))
                v1
1           8/12/2018
2  hello, how are you
3            9/9/2016
4   What is going on?
5    the number three
6           9/18/2015
7               hello
8            9/8/1999
9           not going
10      where to next?
```

I would like to generate a function that will read through each row and move every row that follows a row with a date to a new column and to delete all rows that DO NOT follow dates. My desired output based on the above example is the following:

```
                  v1     value
1           8/12/2018    hello, how are you
2           9/9/2016     What is going on?
3           9/18/2015    hello
4           9/8/1999     not going
```

My intuition is to duplicate `v1` then `lead` it and use `ifelse` to create a new column like in the following but I've had no luck and not sure where to go from there even.

```
df$value<-ifelse(v1="^\d{1,2}\/\d{1,2}\/\d{4}$", lead(v1),"NA")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option is to create a new column from 'v1' as the `lead` of the column and `filter` only the elements that start with numbers or the `Date` format in 'v1'

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>% 
   mutate(value = lead(v1)) %>%
   filter(grepl("^\\d+", v1))
   #or
   #filter(!is.na(mdy(v1)))
#         v1              value
#1 8/12/2018 hello, how are you
#2  9/9/2016  What is going on?
#3 9/18/2015              hello
#4  9/8/1999          not going
```

Answer (score 4):

A base R option using `grep`. First find out indices which strictly follow the date pattern and then create a new dataframe with a new column using the next row of that index.

```
inds <- grep("^\\d{1,2}/\\d{1,2}/\\d{4}$", df$v1)
with(df, data.frame(v1 = v1[inds], value = v1[inds + 1]))

#         v1              value
#1 8/12/2018 hello, how are you
#2  9/9/2016  What is going on?
#3 9/18/2015              hello
#4  9/8/1999          not going
```

Comment: or with `grepl()`: `i <- grepl("/", df$v1);
data.frame(v1=df$v1[i], value=df$v1[which(i)+1])`